# cmakeのadd_custom_target()を使ってdocker buildを呼び出してますが、通常のdocker buildのようにコンソール出力させたい

Tags: docker, build, cmake

CMakeFiles.txtに以下のように記述しています(hoge, fugaは実際の記述から変えています）。

```
find_program(Docker_EXECUTABLE docker)
if(NOT Docker_EXECUTABLE)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "Cannot find the docker executable!")
endif()
add_custom_target(hoge
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../
  COMMAND ${Docker_EXECUTABLE} build -t fuga:latest .
)
```

上記の記述のおかげで `cmake --build .` することで上記の `docker build` 部分が走ることは確認できたのですが、その時にコンソールには以下のような1行しか出力されず、進捗が分からず良くないと思っています。

```
[0/1] /usr/bin/docker build -t fuga:latest .
```

というのも、docker buildの過程で何かユーザーの入力を求めて止まってる場合にそれが分からない、という場面に直面したです。

docker buildした際に通常出力されるコンソール出力を、cmake経由で実行した際にも表示させる方法はないものでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`add_custom_target()`に`USES_TERMINAL`を指定すれば期待する動作になるかと思います。
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_target.html

Comment: ありがとうございます！期待した通りの動作になることが確認できました！